# Is it possible that 2 azure functions can get triggered by one eventhub?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, streaming, azure-eventhub

Is it possible that **2 azure functions** can get **triggered by one eventhub**? One azure function will write its data to database1 and the other azure function writes its data to database2

```
[FunctionName("EventToDB1")]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run([EventHubTrigger("eventhub", Connection = "Debezium")]  
    EventData[] events, ILogger log)
    {
       
            {
[FunctionName("EventToDB2")]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run([EventHubTrigger("eventhub", Connection = "Debezium")]  
        EventData[] events, ILogger log)
     {
        
            {
```

answer on the possibility of having 2 azure functions get triggered by one eventhub

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Will both Functions have to receive the _same_ items? Or will each function receive only specific item types from the same hub? Configuration may differ for those cases.

Comment: you can use output binding and function1 will trigger function2

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible by using different [consumer groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups). Because you specified the same connection to the Event Hub, being *"Debezium"*, I Assume you want both funtions to process the same message. You have to [create a new consumer group](https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/azure-event-hubs-use-consumer-groups-to-support-multiple-subscribers) and specify the name using the `ConsumerGroup` property of the [EventHubTrigger attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.eventhubtriggerattribute.consumergroup?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-webjobs-eventhubtriggerattribute-consumergroup) (The default consumergroup is `$Default`):

```cs
public class EventToDB1
{
    [FunctionName("EventToDB1")]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run(
            [EventHubTrigger("eventhub",
        Connection = "Debezium",
        ConsumerGroup = "CG1")]
        EventData[] events, ILogger log)
    {

    }
}

public class EventToDB2
{
    [FunctionName("EventToDB2")]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run(
        [EventHubTrigger("eventhub",
        Connection = "Debezium",
        ConsumerGroup = "CG2")]
        EventData[] events, ILogger log)
    {

    }
}
```

Each consumer group receives the same messages from the Event Hub.

Comment: is it also possible two have the functions in separated classes?

Comment: @private Sure, not a problem. It could even be deployed to seperate azure function apps. It is just a matter of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @peter bons, you need to create two consumer groups for that and you can create two consumers by below process:

[image]

You can also use logic apps to work with event hubs.